# Aggregate columns for Google Chart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

I'm trying for days with no success to get columns aggregated. I also searched everwhere and found nothing. I want to get column 1 (string with multiple identical values) grouped and sum columns 6,7,8 (numbers) and after I want to select an option to display column 6,7 or 8.

I hope I'm being very clear and a solution would help a lot of people.

Below I would like to share some piece of code.

This example is similar: http://jsfiddle.net/guilhermelight1/fcqeA/80/

I also tried calc: function()...

```
function drawVisualization() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=xxxxxx&sheet=data');

    query.setQuery("select B,I,J,O,P,Q,R,S,T where O is not null Order by Q desc ");
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);

    }


function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
    }

    var data = response.getDataTable();
       var tableChartB = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'Table',
        'containerId': 'table_divB',
                'options': {
                    'width': '100%'
                },
                'view': {'columns': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]}
            }); 



var columnChart2 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
          'containerId': 'Column_div',
          'view': {'columns': [1,6,7,8]},
        'options': {
            'bar': {'groupWidth': '95%'},
            'backgroundColor': 'transparent',
            'animation': {'duration': 1000, 'easing': 'out'},
            'legend': { 'position': 'top', 'alignment': 'start' },
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '90%',
            'chartArea': {'top': '10%', 'width': '85%','height': '80%' },
            'displayAnnotations': 'true',
           'hAxis': {'gridlines': { 'count': 40, 'color': 'transparent' } ,'textStyle':{'fontSize': 8.5}, 'slantedText': false, 'showTextEvery': 1,'minTextSpacing': 0,},
            'tooltip.isHtml': 'true',
            'pointSize': 2,
            'allowHtml': true,
            'vAxis': {'textStyle': {'fontSize': 9,'color': '#585858'},'minTextSpacing': 0},        
        //    'dataTable' : google.visualization.data.group(data, [1],[{'column': 8, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}])

             }}); 


        google.visualization.events.addListener(tableChartB, 'ready',

            function(event) {
                // group the data of the filtered table and set the result in the pie chart.
                columnChart2.setDataTable( google.visualization.data.group(
                // get the filtered results
                tableChartB.getDataTable(),
                [1],
                [{'column': 6, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'},
                {'column': 7, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'},
                {'column': 8, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
            ));
                // redraw the pie chart to reflect changes
                 columnChart2.draw();
            });

            google.visualization.events.addListener(tableChartB, 'statechange',

            function(event) {
                // group the data of the filtered table and set the result in the pie chart.
                columnChart2.setDataTable( google.visualization.data.group(
                // get the filtered results
                tableChartB.getDataTable(),
                [1],
                [{'column': 6, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'},
                {'column': 7, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'},
                {'column': 8, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
            ));
                // redraw the pie chart to reflect changes
                columnChart2.draw();
            });


$('#subc').change(function () {
    var options = $("#subc option");
    var optionSelected = options.index(options.filter(":selected"));
    if (optionSelected === 0) {
        tableChartB.setView({
            'columns':  [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
        });
        columnChart2.setView({
            'columns': [1,6,7,8 ]
        });
        columnChart2.setOption('colors', ["#FFC000","#00b0f0","#ff0000"]);


    } else if (optionSelected === 1) {
        tableChartB.setView({
            'columns':  [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
        });
        columnChart2.setView({
            'columns': [1,{
'type': 'number',
'label': 'Average',
'calc': function (dt, row) {
    return group.getValue(0, 1);
}, 6 ]
        });
        columnChart2.setOption('colors', ["#FFC000"]);


    } else if (optionSelected === 2) {
        tableChartB.setView({
            'columns':  [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
        });
        columnChart2.setView({
            'columns': [1,7]
        });
       columnChart2.setOption('colors', ["#00b0f0"]);

    } else if (optionSelected === 3) {
        tableChartB.setView({
            'columns':  [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
        });
        columnChart2.setView({
            'columns': [1,8 ]
        });
        columnChart2.setOption('colors', ["#ff0000"]);

     } else {
        tableChartB.setView({
            'columns':  [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
        });
        columnChart2.setView({
            'columns': [1,6,7,8 ]
        });
        columnChart2.setOption('colors', ["#FFC000","#00b0f0","#ff0000"]);
    }

    drawChart();
});
```

}

```
     <label class="google-visualization-controls-label"></label>
     <select id="subc" class="filter">
     <option selected="selected" value="a1">Dia-h</option>
                <option value="a2">Dia</option>
                <option value="a3">Calendário</option>
                <option value="a4">Hora</option>
      </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure i completely follow the question, see following working snippet...

adjusted from posted fiddle...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawVisualization,
  packages:['controls']
});

function drawVisualization() {
  // Prepare the data
  var jsonData = '{"cols":[{"label":"Subject","type":"string"},{"label":"pete","type":"number"},{"label":"john","type":"number"},{"label":"carl","type":"number"},{"label":"andrea","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"coolness"},{"v":4.4},{"v":4.3},{"v":3.1},{"v":4.3}]},{"c":[{"v":"sexyness"},{"v":4.2},{"v":3.8},{"v":3.6},{"v":4.8}]},{"c":[{"v":"toughness"},{"v":3.1},{"v":2.7},{"v":2.4},{"v":2.9}]},{"c":[{"v":"chillnes"},{"v":4.4},{"v":4.4},{"v":4.2},{"v":4.5}]},{"c":[{"v":"madness"},{"v":4.6},{"v":4.6},{"v":4},{"v":4.6}]},{"c":[{"v":"lochness"},{"v":3.9},{"v":3.7},{"v":2.9},{"v":3.9}]},{"c":[{"v":"extraness"},{"v":4.6},{"v":4.3},{"v":3.6},{"v":4.3}]},{"c":[{"v":"extraness"},{"v":4.6},{"v":4.3},{"v":3.6},{"v":4.3}]}]}';

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(JSON.parse(jsonData));

  var compPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'control2',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'Subject',
      'ui': {
      'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': true
      }
    }
  });
  // Define a chart
  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
      'containerId': 'chart1',
      'options': {'title':'Competenties',
        'width':'100%',
        'height':300,
        'vAxis': {
          viewWindow: {max:5,min:0},
          gridlines: {color:'#CCC', count: 6}
        },
        bar: { groupWidth: '80%' },
        colors: ["#FFC000","#00b0f0","#ff0000","#92d050"]
      }
  });

  // Define a table
  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'Table',
    'containerId': 'chart2',
    'options': {
      'width': '400px'
    }
  });

  var groupData;
  var groupTable = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'Table',
      containerId: 'chart3',
      options: {
        width: 400
      }
    });
  google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function() {
    groupData = google.visualization.data.group(
      table.getDataTable(),
      [0],
      [
        {
          aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
          column: 1,
          label: data.getColumnLabel(1),
          type: 'number'
        },
        {
          aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
          column: 2,
          label: data.getColumnLabel(2),
          type: 'number'
        },
        {
          aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
          column: 3,
          label: data.getColumnLabel(3),
          type: 'number'
        },
        {
          aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
          column: 4,
          label: data.getColumnLabel(4),
          type: 'number'
        }
      ]
    );
    groupTable.setDataTable(groupData);
    groupTable.draw();
  });

  // Create a dashboard
  var drawChart = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).bind([compPicker], [chart, table]);
  drawChart.draw(data);

  document.getElementById('names').addEventListener('change', function (evt) {
    var colors = ["#FFC000", "#00b0f0", "#ff0000", "#92d050"];
    var viewColumns = {columns: []};
    var viewColors = [];
    switch (evt.target.selectedIndex) {
      case 0:
        $.each(new Array(evt.target.options.length), function (index) {
          viewColumns.columns.push(index);
          if (index > 0) {
            viewColors.push(colors[index - 1]);
          }
        });
        break;

      default:
        viewColumns.columns.push(0);
        viewColumns.columns.push(evt.target.selectedIndex);
        viewColors.push(colors[evt.target.selectedIndex - 1]);
    }
    chart.setView(viewColumns);
    chart.setOption('colors', viewColors);
    groupTable.setView(viewColumns);
    drawChart.draw(data);
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
 <select id="names">
  <option value="0">all</option>
  <option value="1">pete</option>
  <option value="2">john</option>
  <option value="3">carl</option>
  <option value="4">andrea</option>
 </select>
 <table>
  <tr style='vertical-align: top'>
   <td>
    <div id="control1"></div>
    <div id="control2"></div>
    <div id="control3"></div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <div style="float: left;" id="chart1"></div>
    <div style="float: left;" id="chart2"></div>
    <div style="float: left;" id="chart3"></div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me... your example didn't acctually grouped for pet / extraness... I did update a working example http://jsfiddle.net/guilhermelight1/fcqeA/82/ ... but for my code I didn't solve the problem.

Comment: from what i can tell, the example above does group _extraness_, it's just sorted differently...

Comment: I didn't express correctly maybe. If you choose pet and extraness.. you can see sum to 1 bar and not 2 bars..

Comment: not following, when using the group function, _extraness_ is combined into one row, because both rows have the same _subject_

Comment: subject is 9.2 (sum)... I would like to see this result to chart column...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137853/discussion-between-lean-and-whitehat).